# Embedding JQuery in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Working on an `anugularjs` project using a `JQuery` template that contains slides, menu and carousel. How do I embed the `JQuery` main script that handles rendering in `angularjs`.

**I did this:**

```
 $scope.load = function () {
        jQuery('#tp-banner').show().revolution({
            dottedOverlay: "none",
            delay: 6000,
            startwidth: 1170,
            startheight: 700,
            hideThumbs: 200,
            thumbWidth: 100,
            thumbHeight: 50,
            thumbAmount: 5,
            navigationType: "bullet",
            navigationArrows: "solo",
            navigationStyle: "square",
            touchenabled: "on",
            onHoverStop: "off",
            swipe_velocity: 0.7,
            swipe_min_touches: 1,
            swipe_max_touches: 1,
            drag_block_vertical: false,
            parallax: "mouse",
            parallaxBgFreeze: "on",
            parallaxLevels: [7, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
            keyboardNavigation: "off",
            navigationHAlign: "center",
            navigationVAlign: "bottom",
            navigationHOffset: 0,
            navigationVOffset: 20,
            soloArrowLeftHalign: "left",
            soloArrowLeftValign: "center",
            soloArrowLeftHOffset: 20,
            soloArrowLeftVOffset: 0,
            soloArrowRightHalign: "right",
            soloArrowRightValign: "center",
            soloArrowRightHOffset: 20,
            soloArrowRightVOffset: 0,
            shadow: 0,
            fullWidth: "on",
            fullScreen: "off",
            spinner: "spinner4",
            stopLoop: "off",
            stopAfterLoops: -1,
            stopAtSlide: -1,
            shuffle: "off",
            autoHeight: "off",
            forceFullWidth: "off",
            hideThumbsOnMobile: "off",
            hideNavDelayOnMobile: 1500,
            hideBulletsOnMobile: "off",
            hideArrowsOnMobile: "off",
            hideThumbsUnderResolution: 0,
            hideSliderAtLimit: 0,
            hideCaptionAtLimit: 0,
            hideAllCaptionAtLilmit: 0,
            startWithSlide: 0,
            videoJsPath: "rs-plugin/videojs/",
            fullScreenOffsetContainer: ""
        });
    }

    $scope.load();
```

In the above snippet, I tried to embed the slider using a controller but it did not load.

Comment: did you get any error?  Can you check chrome/Firefox console and see if there are any errors?

Comment: this needs to be put into a directive so you are assured the element exists when the code is run. DOM code doesn't belong in controllers

Comment: None of the errors are related to the slide.

Answer (score -1):

Angular is a JS framework that provides the easy way for lot of javascript complex task. And jQuery is a JavaScript UI library.

That means you'll need to put it into your view, not the controller, because they are different things.

Into your `index.html` file, put this line:

```
<script src="/path/to/libs/folder/jquery-X.x.x.min.js />
```

This will load your jQuery library in your index, so it is available for the views (in Angular, views will be rendered with the index).

Now, in your view, inside `<script>` tags, insert your jQuery code.

You won't need scopes for this task :)

Comment: but angular strips script tags from templates

Comment: Instead of downvoting, try to answer the question.